# OS X El Capitan find mouse dosen't work with external mouse

Tags: mouse, macos

Yesterday I installed El Capitan 10.11 (15A204h) and liked it a ton and intend to be use it exclusively from now on. I really liked the feature where you can shake the mouse to find the cursor and was very disappointed to find it didn't work when I tried with an external mouse.

Does anyone have any hacks or methods to get this to work? I think it's a really good feature and I don't want to not have it when working with external mouses and displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know a hack to make it work. It's called "tell Apple that there's a bug in their **beta** software."

Seriously, don't expect flawless performance from features that still have every right to be half-baked. Open Feedback Assistant and file a report in the hope that Apple will have it fixed by the time El Capitan gets its stable release. Odds are other beta testers are having your problem too, so it's your duty as a tester to report all the bugs you can find.

Comment: As much as this is an option, it's not really a very constructive error. You're absolutely correct about the implied contract between the vendor issuing a beta and the consumer using the beta to report and address problem reports.

Comment: Um i dont have Feedback Assistant (:

Comment: Really? That's strange. I thought all beta testers had it. Maybe find a friend who has it and get them to send you the app?

Comment: Feedback Assistant is a tool for users on the public beta, which isn't released yet. Developer Previews don't have the Feedback Assistant as you are expected to post bugs through the developer channels.

Comment: well i submitted it on the Yosemite feedback assistant and through dev channels then it got fixed